# Facebook comments box position

Tags: javascript, css, facebook, facebook-comments

Please help,

I have recently added the facebook comments box to my site (arabic site), but the problem is
that the position of the box is moving to the left ... this is an example of my site
http://www.alamelnokta.com/nokate/show/100

Any idea please to fix the position of the box.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following to your CSS:

```
.fb_iframe_widget iframe {
    left: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the position for this element to become `absolute` rather than `<style="position:relative">`.

Comment: thanks for your help, but is not working... i find that the problem is this element `.fb_iframe_widget iframe` and it is from the facebook itself and i can't change it

Comment: Oh i see. Yeah that makes sense also. I think @3rror404 has beaten me to the other suggestion I had after actually looking into your code.

Comment: No worries. :) Glad I could be of help. Mark this question as answered so it can help others in the future. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `left:0`:

```
.fb_iframe_widget iframe{
   position:absolute;
   left:0;
}
```